# Trying to have my python program add the total values after the loop, but it outputs the final values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Variables
total = 0
day = 0
car = 0

while day <= 4:
  day += 1

  if day <= 5:
    print('Cars sold on day', day, end = ': ',)
    carSold = int(input(''))

    for amount in range(carSold):
      print('Selling price of car', amount + 1, end = ':\t')
      price = int(input('$'))

  if day >= 5:
    total += price
    car += carSold
    print('\nYou sold', car, 'cars for a total of $', format(total,',.2f'))
```

The different configurations I have tried all either add after every input or just the last value.

Answer (score 1):

You added values to `total` and `car` only at the last day, while the code below is adding values everyday.

```
#Variables
total = 0
car = 0

for day in range(1, 6):
    carSold = int(input('Cars sold on day {}: '.format(day)))
    car += carSold

    for amount in range(carSold):
        total += int(input('Selling price of car {}: $'.format(amount+1)))

    if day == 5:
        print('\nYou sold', car, 'cars for a total of $', format(total,',.2f'))
```

Comment: You are the bomb.com. Can you explain what the format for day and amount+1 does?

Comment: They replace `{}` to input argument.(https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
Writing concise code is very important in Python, and so is error checking since it is very easy to spawn an error by typing anything other than a number:

```
total = 0
day = 0
car = 0
carSold = 0
lastsold = 0


while day <= 4:
    day += 1
    try:
        if day <= 5:
            lastsold += int(input('Cars sold on day %i: '%day))
            carSold += lastsold

        for amount in range(carSold):
            total += int(input('Selling price of car %i: $'%(amount+1)))
    except:
        day -= 1
        carSold -= lastsold
        continue
    lastsold = 0

    if day >= 5:
        print('\nYou sold %i cars for a total of $%.2f'%(car,total))
```